# PHP: One big echo (or print) VS many small echo (or print)

Tags: php, optimization

I should `echo` a table with 1000 rows of data, can I `echo` all the data in one string or is it better to `echo` a row per time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to http://phplens.com/lens/php-book/optimizing-debugging-php.php (see last third of article) you should use one big echo statement, and use single quotes instead of double quotes, so PHP hasn´t to check for variables within the string.

simple test for support:

```
$bgn = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<=1000; $i++)
{
  echo $i;
}
echo "\n", round(microtime(true)-$bgn, 4), "\n";
unset($bgn);
$bgn = microtime(true);
$b = '';
for ($i=0; $i<=1000; $i++)
{
  $b.=$i;
}
echo $b;
echo "\n", round(microtime(true)-$bgn, 4), "\n";
?>
```

First run return `0.0022`, while second run return `0.0007` ... however this is small set of data, memory usage is quite small.

Comment: yes, an the article shows a very good example how to optimize such a loop with echos etc...

Comment: Although it says nothing of single quotes, so, it's only you

Comment: if you use double quotes, php tries to find variables within the string to parse them, with single quotes: it doesn´t, so it´s a little bit faster.

Answer (score 5):

I would echo line by line. This way you save memory (no need to load all lines in memory before outputting them).

Answer (score 1):

echo row per time, using lesser buffer memory and less memory (you don't need to use a variable to hold the data)

based on the tested that I conducted for the selected answer, it show opposite

Answer (score 1):

This is old, and some of it is outdated, but you should still definitely read [How Long Is a Piece of String?](http://blog.golemon.com/2006/06/how-long-is-piece-of-string.html)

That said, unless you've already heavily optimized everything else, it's unlikely that `echo` is your bottleneck.

Comment: Just wanted to say that your link points to an interesting article about PHP opcodes. Very informative even if one's not interested in optimization.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your aim. Time consumption usually is no issue depending on the number of fields, so is the mermory usage for this action (todays memory is large enough to cause no problems withonly 1000 rows).

My feeling tells me it might be more practical to echo it line by line in order to do modifications, but i think it is not a big deal at all. Do what you like.

Answer (score 0):

As Pekka said, it doesn't matter. Do it in the way that makes your code best readable (by using a **template** preferably, instead of just lame echo within mysql fetch array loop).

When (if ever) it become a bottleneck - **profile** it first, and optimize then. Based on the real life numbers, not rumors.

As for the particular 1000-rows table - paginate it, silly. just paginate.
Make your app not to do useless job. That's the **real** secret of optimization.